# How to fix "unexpected alert open: {Alert text : } " error

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I have a project in ruby with AngularJS and I'm currently converting tests over to Headless chrome from Phantomjs, and I keep getting an error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError:
            unexpected alert open: {Alert text : }
```

This happens throughout multiple test files..
I have tried adding

"accept_alert {} " before a command :

```
#from

find('.sp-advanced-configuration').click

#to
accept_alert{ find('.sp-advanced-configuration').click  }
```

but receive

```
Failure/Error: accept_alert{ ... }

          Capybara::ModalNotFound:
            Unable to find modal dialog
```

as well as

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError:
            unexpected alert open: {Alert text : }
```

Not sure what else to try

/*********** *********/

After looking into this further, It seems the issue occurs whenever there are unsaved changes left on the test before moving onto the next test.

Is there a way where you can accept this for every test without having to add

```
 after do 
    execute_script('window.onbeforeunload = undefined')
  end
```

in every test file?

Comment: you can set the webdriver to accept all alerts.  The "ignore" setting will throw the unexpected alert error.  See "setUnhandledPromptBehaviour" of ChromeOptions: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html#setUnhandledPromptBehaviour-org.openqa.selenium.UnexpectedAlertBehaviour-

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're seeing this is that Poltergesit/PhantomJS used to automatically accept unexpected system modals. The selenium driver doesn't do that because your test should actively either accept or decline it.  Is  `find('.sp-advanced-configuration').click` the action that opens the alert box?  From the errors you're getting I would guess not. The block `accept_alert` receives needs to be the block that actually triggers the opening of the system modal. This means your code probably needs to be

```
accept_alert { # action that triggers the alert }
find('.sp-advanced-configuration').click
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Thomas! Unfortunately, this doesn't help. I've looked into the issue further and explained it above.

Comment: @PhilCollins what version of Capybara are you using and have you disabled the normal session resetting? In the default configuration a recent version of Capybara should suppress alerts handle alerts when attempting to reset